# How does Google Analytics detect browser/version?

Tags: google-analytics, electron

We've built an electron app, and are running a webapp with google analytics inside one of a webview tag. However, all traffic is showing up as from Chrome, not from our app's name (and we want to differentiate)

We've tried several different user agents, and traffic keeps showing up from chrome. User Agents we've tried:

- Default Electron: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) OurAppName/3.2.0 Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Electron/2.0.2 Safari/537.36`
- Custom: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) OurAppName/3.2.0`

Is there a way to set the browser and browser version detected as our custom app name in google analytics via the js API? Are we doing something wrong with the user agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Browser detection is done on server side**
Because browser/device detection is a complex task, doing it on the client side would make the client-side library too big and impact performance. So the way it works:

1. GA client library sends the user agent
2. GA servers process user agent and extract browser

**Manipulating browser detection**
Since processing is done by GA servers, nobody knows exactly how it's done. Looking at the [measurement protocol documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua) it says:

> Google has libraries to identify real user agents. Hand crafting your
>   own agent could break at any time.

So my guess is that your hand crafted user agents are not recognized by GA which falls back to chrome.

You could [have a look at this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) to review the User Agent syntax and see if you could craft your own in a way GA accepts it, but once again there is no guarantee it will work.

**Bot Filtering**
Last but not least, you might want to uncheck the `Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders` option in the view settings, which might exclude all your electron traffic, thus you're not seeing it no matter which user agent combinations you're trying

[image]